# SSRS - How a parameter dropdown display show english or french description

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How a parameter dropdown display show english or french description that is coming from a stored procedure which is returning both english and french desc?

Comment: do you have a field for for each description (english and french)?

Comment: yes desc and desc_fr

Comment: when do you want to show the english description instead of the french description? is there a condition to choose what description to show?. Also You can show both let me know if that meets your requeriment.

Comment: =iif(Left(User!Language,2)="fr", french, english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than returning both English and French descriptions you should pass a language parameter to the stored procedure and return the description for the language specified by the parameter. The value for the language can be passed to the report as a parameter, or picked up from the built in SSRS user language property which is picked up from the user setting in the browser.